# When a page loads can it pass data to an ES6 module?

Tags: javascript

I am writing an app where some of the data to be used in the app is fixed and not going to change once the page is loaded. Other data is changing all the time and is brought into the app by ajax when the user clicks a button. This data needs to be combined with the fixed data for displaying to the user every time they click the button.

I want to use ES6 modules for this app. The solution I have attempted is shown below. In reality the variable, fixedData, would be quite a large data structure which is why I definitely do not want to get it by ajax every time the user clicks the button as that would be unnecessary and take time transferring data. Here I have used the value 6 for fixedData to keep the example simple.

The line, `const fixedData = 6`, would be made as PHP generates the page like this: `const fixedData = '<?php echo 6; ?>';

index.php:

```
<script type='module' src='./main.js'>
    const fixedData = 6;
</script>
```

main.js:

```
const h2 = document.createElement('h2');

function displayFixedData(fixedData){
    h2.innerText = data;
    document.body.appendChild(h2);
}

displayFixedData(fixedData);
```

When I run this, I get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: fixedData is not defined'

Is there some way I can feed fixed data into my JavaScript code on page load and which would be available for using as an argument in functions inside ES6 modules in the app?

I feel like I need to export the data from the script tag and import it into main.js although I believe that is not possible. Is there some other way I can achieve that?

**Edit:**

In response to Barmar's comment I now have something which does work:

index.php

```
<script type="module">
    import { displayFixedData } from './main.js'
    const fixedData = 5;
    displayFixedData(fixedData);
</script>
```

main.js:

```
const h2 = document.createElement('h2');

function displayFixedData(fixedData){
    h2.innerText = fixedData;
    document.body.appendChild(h2);
}

export { displayFixedData };
```

Comment: You can't have both `src` and inline content of the script. If the script has `src` it ignores the inline contents.

Comment: The module should export the function, then you should call the function in the next script after loading the module.

Comment: @Barmar I don't quite see what you mean. Would that allow me to pass fixedData to the function?

Comment: Yes, do `displayFixedData(<?php echo 6 ?>)`

Comment: @Barmar I have edited my question to something which does work. I think it is essentially what you were suggesting. Does it seem a feasible approach? Presumably most of my code could be in various modules so long as they were finally imported into the script tag to be combined with the fixedData??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a non-executable `<script>` element containing some text serialization of data, e.g. JSON:

```php
<script id="fixed-data" type="application/json">
    <?= json_encode($fixedData, JSON_HEX_TAG) ?>
</script>

<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

(The `JSON_HEX_TAG` flag escapes `<`, preventing HTML injection (XSS) issues with data containing `<!--` or `</script>`.)

Then select and deserialize in your script:

```js
const fixedData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('fixed-data').textContent);
```

Comment: I have just implemented that and then looked at the html with the browser's developer tools and seen the fixedData inside the script tag. It looks like a very useful thing to be able to do!