# Efficient way to store information in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list

I need to store inside my Java Script code some coordinates. At first there were just 10 or 20 coordinates, however now there are like 50 and it starts to be really messy. Inside my code i stored the information as a list:

```
function mia_posizione(position) {
    
    let latitudini = [45.830527, 45.879442, 46.017065, 46.045482, 46.025059, 45.980489, 46.029090, 46.084223, 45.836633, 45.837948, 45.837878, 45.834405, 45.836208, 45.832634, 46.481307];
    let longitudini = [9.029344, 8.979577, 8.931969, 8.978964, 8.965355, 8.926994, 8.969981, 9.036319, 9.032914, 9.026279, 9.023992, 9.035057, 9.034544, 9.021575, 9.916223];
    for(let i=0; i<latitudini.length; i++){
        var latLocation =  latitudini[i];
        var lonLocation = longitudini[i];
        var latUser = position.coords.latitude;
        var lonUser = position.coords.longitude;
        var R = 6371;
        var dLat = deg2rad(latLocation - latUser);
        var dLon = deg2rad(lonLocation - lonUser);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(latUser)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(latLocation)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        var y = R * c;
        var Approssimazione = aprox(y)
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("data-index", y);
        const Raggio = document.getElementById(i);
        if(Raggio.dataset.index>1000){
            document.getElementById(i).style.display="none"; 
        }
    }
}
```

The coordinates you see are just some of the many. Is there a way I can easily store and have access to them?

Comment: You can put them inside an element as a JSON string. Then they are accessible from any JavaScript code whether that is inside a module or other file. See the accepted answer to the question I asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144562/when-a-page-loads-can-it-pass-data-to-an-es6-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to format it or add spaces in your list so it's more readable. This is what I did. Let me know what you think.

```
function mia_posizione(position) {

let latitudini = [45.830527, 45.879442, 46.017065, 46.045482,
                  46.025059, 45.980489, 46.029090, 46.084223,
                  45.836633, 45.837948, 45.837878, 45.834405,
                  45.836208, 45.832634, 46.481307];

let longitudini = [9.029344, 8.979577, 8.931969, 8.978964,
                   8.965355, 8.926994, 8.969981, 9.036319,
                   9.032914, 9.026279, 9.023992, 9.035057,
                   9.034544, 9.021575, 9.916223];
for(let i=0; i<latitudini.length; i++){
    var latLocation =  latitudini[i];
    var lonLocation = longitudini[i];
    var latUser = position.coords.latitude;
    var lonUser = position.coords.longitude;
    var R = 6371;
    var dLat = deg2rad(latLocation - latUser);
    var dLon = deg2rad(lonLocation - lonUser);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(latUser)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(latLocation)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var y = R * c;
    var Approssimazione = aprox(y)
    document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("data-index", y);
    const Raggio = document.getElementById(i);
    if(Raggio.dataset.index>1000){
        document.getElementById(i).style.display="none"; 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you can add them in a js file where you define the data for example `coordinates.js`

```
var coordinates = [
     {latitudini: 45.830527, longitudini: 9.029344},
     {latitudini: 45.879442, longitudini: 8.979577},
];
```

and in html just include this file when ever you want to use this info

`<script src="coordinates.js"></script>`

now your code will look like so

```
function mia_posizione(position) {
    for(let i=0; i< coordinates.length; i++){
        var latLocation =  coordinates[i].latitudini;
        var lonLocation = coordinates[i].longitudini;
        var latUser = position.coords.latitude;
        var lonUser = position.coords.longitude;
        var R = 6371;
        var dLat = deg2rad(latLocation - latUser);
        var dLon = deg2rad(lonLocation - lonUser);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(latUser)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(latLocation)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        var y = R * c;
        var Approssimazione = aprox(y)
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("data-index", y);
        const Raggio = document.getElementById(i);
        if(Raggio.dataset.index>1000){
            document.getElementById(i).style.display="none"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get them into the js file if they are dynamic (ie. coming from a database and changing from one visit to the web page to the next)? If you put them inside a script tag in your HTML as a JSON string then they can be written there dynamically when the page loads (eg with PHP) and then read from any JS file.

Comment: @user3425506 if they are dynamic or coming from database then they won't be hard coded in the code as mentioned in the question so probably the question is referring to hard coded coordinates

Comment: 'probably' but not necessarily